# How to have Azure VM auto-stop after windows Updates are installed

Tags: azure

I'm running Windows Updates on my `Azure Windows Server 2016 VM` that are taking too much time. How can I have `VM` auto-stop after updates are installed (instead of me keep checking if the updates are done)?

Answer (score -1):

In Azure VM , as I known, there is no more ways to do it. Other choice is to make your own calculation of how many time it could delay the installation. You can create a batch file (or just WinKey+R) with this command: `shutdown -s -t n` where `n` is the time in seconds that system will be delay to shutdown. As note, you can use `shutdown -r -t n` where `-r` indicates a restart.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Voting down because shutdown of the guest OS will not save any Azure costs. You have to stop the VM from the portal to save costs. I believe this concern is implied in the question but the Op can confirm.

Comment: @GregGalloway Yes, the concern is about Azure costs meter keep running while I'm still waiting the OS Windows Server 2016 updates are still running - and I would like to know how to have VM stopped automatically after Updates are done instead of me keep waiting for updates to be done so I could manually stop the VM from portal.

Comment: Hi,@GregGalloway and nam. Deallocating Azure VM can save cost. you can scheduler your VM from Azure portal, but as my answer said, you cannot automatically shutdown your VM after updating.